# Skip to next step if cancel is pressed in InputBox

Tags: vba, excel, inputbox

I am currently running a macro with the InputBox code shown below:

```
ActiveCell.Value = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the sample name", Title:="Sample name")
```

It works great for when I don't have any text in the ActiveCell already, but if there is text in there already, it clears the text if I hit cancel.

How can I change this so that if I hit cancel at this step, then it will just skip to the next step and not change what is in the cell already? I don't want it to end the sub, I just want it to skip to the next line in the code.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
Dim s as String
s = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the sample name", Title:="Sample name")
If s <>"" Then ActiveCell.Value = s
```

Comment: That still didn't work. It just deleted what was in the cell and moved on like it was doing before.

Comment: please check again - the vital `<>` got lost upon pasting - I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim a As Variant
a = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter name", Title:="Sample name")
If a <> False Then
    ActiveCell.Value = a
End If
```